# Best way to get rid of the smell of cooking flesh (meat)?

Tags: living-with-omnivores, sustainability

How do I clear the smell of meat?

A few times per week, my housemate buys body parts from the store and burns them in the oven for a few hours. The resulting smell is horrendous.

Of course, I open the windows for a few minutes at a time to help clear the air, but it's freezing outside and I'm also trying to reduce my carbon footprint.

What can I do to overcome this smell in my apartment?

Answer (score 3):

The best is always to communicate with your housemates. Try to be calm and tell them that the smell is making you nauseous. If there's a kitchen fan, politely ask them if they can please turn it on before they start cooking.

If possible, open the windows for at least a few minutes after they're done cooking to clear the air.

You should also try to contain the smell and distance yourself from its source. If the kitchen has a door, make sure it's closed. While they're cooking, try go to another room as far away as possible. Shut the door to *your* room too, and try to make it air-tight by putting a towel under the door.

Other than that, here's a few things you can do to overpower the smell

#### Produce Fresh Steam

Cut a lemon into thin slices and boil it in a big pot of water.

Optionally, add spices to the water for a potpourri scent: cloves, allspice, nutmeg, cinnamon, etc

Optionally, add essential oils to the water: lavender and rose are nice. This is also known as a steam diffuser.

#### Scented Fire

Burn some incense or a scented candle.

Even just lighting a match and blowing it out may help because the resulting smoke is powerful.

#### Cook smelly vegan food

You may be able to mask the smell by cooking something yourself. Many vegan dishes can smell very strong, such as:

1. Indian Curry
2. Roasted Veggies
3. (Deep) Fried Falafel
4. etc

#### Chemical Spray

I wouldn't recommend it, but many consumers buy chemicals under-pressure cans and spray them. Popular brands are Fabreeze, Lysol, etc.